# How to access a parent model from one of my fk fields?

Tags: django

I'am trying to access a parent instance from its child.

I have the following models

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
   user_name = models.Charfield()
   points = models.Charfield()

class ModelB(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
   points = models.Charfield()

class ModelC(models.Model):
   model_b = models.OneToOne(ModelB)
   info = models.TextField()
```

And I'am doing a query like this:

```
ModelB.objects.filter({somefilters}).values('user__user_name')
```

But I want to check if there is a reference to B in C, and if there is get the info. I can't start from ModelC as:

```
ModelC.objects.filter({somefilers}).values('model_b__user__user_name')
```

Because there maybe or not a record relating both models.

Is possible starting from ModelB to get info from its parent ModelC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make use of the [**`__isnull`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) here:

```
ModelB.objects.filter(
    modelc__isnull=False
).values('user__user_name')
```

Here we thus check if there is a `ModelC` that points to that `ModelB` object.

You can access the related `modelc` object as well, for example in your values, like:

```
ModelB.objects.filter(
    modelc__isnull=False
).values('user__user_name', 'modelc__info')
```

This will thus result in a `JOIN` where we `JOIN` the `ModelC.model_b` field on the `ModelB.pk`.

If you use:

```
ModelB.objects.values('user__user_name', 'modelc__info')
```

It will return `None` for `modelc__info` given *no* such related `ModelC` exists.

Comment: Interesting, but what I need exactly is to get some info from ModelC IF such relation exist, like .values('modelc__info'), this sounds a little bit silly but is kind of what I need. And for modelc__isnull to work should I put a verbose name somewhere? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @JuanEstebanLadronDeGuevara: in that case, you probably do not need a `.filter(..)`, but just use `.values(..)` since it will return `None` if no such `ModelC` exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a related name on Model C like:

```
class ModelC(models.Model):
   model_b = models.OneToOne(ModelB, related_name='modelc')
   info = models.TextField()
```

And in your queryset:

```
ModelB.objects.filter({somefilters}).values('user__user_name', 'modelc__info')
```

If you don't want to set a related name you can use: `model_b_set__info` instead of `modelc__info`

Comment: Yep, as you were thinking, you cant get the value like that. But I should not make another query on modelc, this filter will return several records and I do not want to hit the DB N times. What do you think?